# Is there any way to increase the bomb timer in Counter Strike 1.6?

Tags: counter-strike

I want to play as a Counter Terrorist against all bot Ts. So I want to increase the timer for the bomb going off. I want to increase it to lets say 120 secs before going off. Is there any way to do that in Counter Strike 1.6?

Answer (score 1):

**mp_c4timer** [value]

You can set it anywhere between 15 and 90 (seconds). The default value is 45 and competitive games are usually using 35.